# Problems using session based cookies in Django

Tags: python, django, session, cookies

I am working on the Tango With Django tutorial, and I am trying to use session based cookies to count the number of times a user visits a website.  When the user visits the about page, they should see a message telling them how often they have visited the website.  First I made sure that django.contrib.sessions is listed under my INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rango',
)
```

I then ran 'python manage.py syncdb'.  My sessions are handled in views.py like so:

```
def index(request):
  context_dict = {}

  category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
  category_list = remove_spaces(category_list)
  context_dict['categories'] = category_list

  page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
  context_dict['pages'] = page_list

  # Deal with cookies
  if request.session.get('last_visit'):
    last_visit_time = request.session.get('last_visit')
    visits = request.session.get('visits', 0)

    # Use seconds instead of days for testing
    if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").seconds > 5:
      request.session['visits'] = visits + 1
      request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
    else:
      request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
      request.session['visits'] = 1

  return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)

def about(request):
  if request.session.get('visits'):
    count = request.session.get('visits')
  else:
    count = 0

  context_dict = {'boldmessage': 'here is the about page','visits': count}
  return render(request, 'rango/about.html', context_dict)
```

Here is my about template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  {% extends 'rango/base.html' %}

  {% load static %}

  {% block title %}About{% endblock %}

  {% block body_block %}
    <h1>Rango says...</h1>
    <strong>{{ boldmessage }}</strong>
    <h3>You have visited this site {{ visits }} times</h3>
    <img src="{% static 'icon_12544.png' %}" alt="Diving helmet" />
  {% endblock %}

</html>
```

Whenever I go that page, I just see that the user has visited the site 0 times.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The index view just has one level of indentation to many when you're checking for the presence of the session cookie:

```
def index(request):
  context_dict = {}

  category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
  category_list = remove_spaces(category_list)
  context_dict['categories'] = category_list

  page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
  context_dict['pages'] = page_list

  # Deal with cookies
  if request.session.get('last_visit'):
    last_visit_time = request.session.get('last_visit')
    visits = request.session.get('visits', 0)

    # Use seconds instead of days for testing
    if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").seconds > 5:
      request.session['visits'] = visits + 1
      request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
  else:
    # this code was never reached, so the session was not being set
    request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
    request.session['visits'] = 1

  return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Doh!  I had an error with the datetime functions in the second if statement as well: `if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days > 0`